# Divide by Zero Error encountered in Snowflake Query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have the following snowflake query where I am getting a divide by zero error...Can you please help me here..

```
with cte1 as 
(select * from "coe.cup"
where typeofcare ='AM'
and status ='DONE'
and review ='false'
and date (assigneddate)>='2021-04-01'), cte2 as(
select cast(completed as date) completeddate ,iscode
 ,iff(iscode=1,datediff(minute,assigneddate,coded),0) codeddatetime
 ,iff(iscode=0,datediff(minute,assigneddate,qaed),0) qaeddatetime
 ,datediff(minute,assigneddate,completed) overall  from 
 (select *,iff(qaed='1900-01-01 00:00:00.0000000',1,0) iscode from cte1)a )
 select completeddate 
 ,sum(iff(iscode=1,1,0)) noofvisitbillscoded
 ,sum(iff(iscode=1,0,1)) noofvisitbillscodedandqaed
 ,count(1) totalvisitbillscompleted
 ,cast(sum(codeddatetime)/sum(iff(iscode=1,1,0)) as float)/60 averagetimeforcodedvisitbills
 ,cast(sum(qaeddatetime)/sum(iff(iscode=1,0,1)) as float)/60  averagetimeforcodedandqaedvisitbills
 ,cast(sum(overall)/count(1) as float)/60 overallaveragetime
 from cte2
 group by completeddate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that this happens due to the `/sum(iff(iscode=1,1,0))` where this presumably sometimes returns 0.

One aproach to deal with division by zero is to use `NULLIF`

```
NULLIF( <expr1> , <expr2> )
```

returns `NULL` if `expr1` is equal to `expr2`, otherwise returns `expr1`.

So, in your code where you have, for example `sum(iff(iscode=1,1,0))`, you can replace this with:

```
NULLIF(sum(iff(iscode = 1, 1, 0)), 0)
```

and this should then return `NULL` instead of causing a division by zero.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to to use the DIV0 function so something like:

```
DIV0(sum(codeddatetime),sum(iff(iscode=1,1,0))
```

More info here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/div0.html

Answer (score 3):

When division is involved the divisor could be handled with **[NULLIFZERO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nullifzero.html)**:

> NULLIFZERO(  )
>
> Returns NULL if the argument evaluates to 0; otherwise, returns the argument.

Second pattern `sum(iff(iscode=1,1,0))` is a conditional sum that emulates filtered COUNT. It could be further simplfied with **[COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html)**

> COUNT_IF(  )
>
> Returns the number of records that satisfy a condition.

To sum up:

```
,cast(sum(codeddatetime)/sum(iff(iscode=1,1,0)) as float)/60 

=>
,SUM(codeddatetime)/NULLIFZERO(COUNT_IF(iscode=1))/60 

=> if iscode is boolean column then:
,SUM(codeddatetime)/NULLIFZERO(COUNT_IF(iscode))/60
```